how to count the number of pipe ends in this photo using CoreML?
[I want to select an object in a photo and then count the number of these objects


    func compareImages(fullImage: UIImage, fragmentImage: UIImage) {
    guard let fullCIImage = CIImage(image: fullImage),
          let fragmentCIImage = CIImage(image: fragmentImage) else {
        fatalError("Unable to create CIImage")
    }
    
    guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: model) else {
        fatalError("Unable to load CoreML model")
    }
    
    let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { (request, error) in
        guard let results = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation], 
              let topResult = results.first else {
            fatalError("Unable to classify images")
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(results)
        }
    }
    
    let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: fullCIImage, options: [:])
    
    do {
        try handler.perform([request])
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    }

`
